# Mysterious Behavior of .NET Core Background Task

Tags: c#, .net-core, backgroundworker

my first question is if this article by Microsoft is working for other programers: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/

There is explained how i can use background-services. I have a program which has a WEB API where the data input is inserted to a database. My background job should show every minute if there is new data in the database and should handle some request to other webservices.

My problem is, that sometimes it triggers twice or the job isn't running. I print to the console every time the background service is doing it's job the timestamp. And after a while there is nothing printed out anymore.

Here is my sample-code. Is there something wrong with my code or configuration?

First Code-Sample is the code of the Startup-Class in the ConfigureService Method:

```
//Adding Background Task Class to Hosted Services in Startup-Class and Method ConfigureServices
services.AddHostedService<JsonDataCreator>();
```

Here is the implementation of the class which holds the logic of my background service:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Background Service which creates the JSON Files for the machine
/// </summary>
public class JsonDataCreator : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">Logger functionallity</param>
    public JsonDataCreator(ILogger<JsonDataCreator> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Task which is executed Asynchronous
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Cancellation token for stopping the Task</param>
    /// <returns>Task Completed</returns>
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting");
        Console.WriteLine("Timed Background Service is starting");
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logical Request to Webservice + Database and creation of JSON Files
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Begin new Round of Background-Work" +                                     DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            //THERE IS SOME LOGIC INSIDE WHICH CALLS SOME WEBSERVICE
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }                 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the Task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns>Task Completed</returns>
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping");
        Console.WriteLine("Timed Background Service is stopping");
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the Task
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in here that suggests the task will run twice. When it stops running, do you see the equivalent message in the log that `StopAsync` was called? Also, I would destroy the timer in `StopAsync` rather than change the interval.

Comment: @DavidG The mysterious stuff is, that the background task is definitiv not longer executed but the stopasync is also not fired. so i have no idea where the problem is. Is a background-task in general made for a solution like this?

Comment: @stuartd thats correct. the methods StopAsync and so on are named by the interface. currently i don't need any asynchronous functionallities

Comment: why don't you use an endless-while and remove the timer? it works perfectly, and avoids the mixing of threads (timer) and tasks.

Comment: @MarioVernari I want to wait a minute before the next execution cycle is starting

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler add `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))` in the loop body.

Comment: Make that `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), cancellationToken)`

Comment: @MarioVernari could you give me a code sample? I tried it - it doesn't work

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler since the post was of four months ago, which version of Net Core 2.0 are you using? Have a look at the `BackgroundService` -derivation. The example here looks very much that you want to do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/

Comment: @MarioVernari i'm using now .net core 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the provided solution with an endless loop. From now, there is no mysterious behavior about timeouts and cancelled tasks.

The solution looks like the following:

```
     /// <summary>
/// Background Service which creates the JSON Files for the machine
/// </summary>
public class JsonDataCreator : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">Logger functionallity</param>
    public JsonDataCreator(ILogger<JsonDataCreator> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Task which is executed Asynchronous
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">Cancellation token for stopping the Task</param>
    /// <returns>Task Completed</returns>
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is starting");
        while(true){
            //Do the business logic
            //Wait the time you want
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the Task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns>Task Completed</returns>
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Background Service is stopping");
        Console.WriteLine("Timed Background Service is stopping");
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the Task
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hopefully it helps you too.

Comment: so you can never stop the service? xD i dont think that was smart

Comment: @Ramomex1 its build in a docker container - so i can stop the container and the job is done.